# Destroy method in Interceptor

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I have given `destroy` method in interceptors in Struts2. When will this method is called and what is the use of it?
I want to call this method during server shutdown. But this method is not getting called.

Comment: May be you need a dispatcher listener, it will send you notification on shutdown.

Comment: You used use a context listener for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The destroy method is called, when the container or application is stopped or un-deployed to let an interceptor clean up any resources it has allocated but         **[#destroy](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/Interceptor.html#destroy%28%29)() is not reliable**.

> It’s not recommend to put any code inside the destroy(), because this
>   method is not reliable. When your application server is force shutdown
>   or be killed by command, the destroy() will not be called.

Comment: will this method be called if the server shut downs??

Comment: @M.M.RAMKUMAR: It will be called only if server shutdown properly.

Comment: if i shutdown the server using terminal will it be called? But while am using it in eclipse this method is not getting called.